# Not able to read configuration from Consul in spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I am creating a `Spring Boot` application, which will read configuration like DB properties from `Consul`. But I am not able to read the key value from Consul using my application. Following is, what I am trying to do.

```
**pom.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tuturself</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-consul</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.retry.version>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring.retry.version>
        <consul.version>1.1.2.RELEASE</consul.version>
        <consul.discovery.version>1.1.2.RELEASE</consul.discovery.version>
        <jackson.version>2.8.1</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>${consul.discovery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.retry.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

**And Following is my Main class:**

```
@EnableRetry
@RefreshScope
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.test.*")
public class SpringBootConsulApplication {

    private static ConsulConfiguration consulConfiguration;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String consulHost = System.getProperty("spring.cloud.consul.host");
            System.out.println("consulHost ::" + consulHost);
            String consulPort = System.getProperty("spring.cloud.consul.port");
            System.out.println("consulPort ::" + consulPort);
            String consulPrefix = System.getProperty("spring.cloud.consul.config.prefix");
            System.out.println("consulPrefix ::" + consulPrefix);
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootConsulApplication.class).web(true).run(args);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I am reading the consul properties using the `@Value` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PropertySourceBootstrapProperties.class)
public class ConsulConfiguration {

    @Value("${cassandra.host}")
    private String cassandraHost;

    @Value("${cassandra.user}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${cassandra.password}")
    private String password;
}
```

I have my `bootstrap.yml` in resources folder:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      enabled: true
      config:
        enabled: true
        prefix: config/application
        defaultContext: apps
        profileSeparator: '::'
  application:
    name: spring-boot-consul
```

Consul is up and running in my local system on `localhost:8500` where I have the file `config/application/spring-boot-consul.yml` file;

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-boot-consul
cassandra:
  host: 127.0.0.1:9042,127.0.0.2:9042
  user: my_user
  password: my_pass
  pooling:
    maxThread: 10
    timeout: 50
  keyspace:
    name: test_keyspace
    readConsistency: ONE
    writeConsistency: ONE
```

When I am strating the application, it is showing not able to bind `cassandra.host` in my `ConsulConfiguration`  class. Thus stopping the application. Any hints , What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try setting spring.cloud.consul.config.format in the bootstrap.yml file, as per the documentation?

Comment: Can you check by removing annotation from configuration class @EnableConfigurationProperties(PropertySourceBootstrapProperties.class)

Comment: How did you start your consul agent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-consul-example).

#### Consul Configuration KV Store

You need to store your properties in the Consul KV store either from Consul UI or from the command line. **The Consul Agent will not load your properties from the file system**. To load the properties from the command line, you can use the following command once the Consul Agent is up and running. The YAML data can be read from a file by prefixing the file name with the @ symbol.

```
./consul kv put config/application/data @spring-boot-consul.yml
```

where `config/application/data` is the key name.

If the data is successfully written in the KV, you should get the following response,

```
Success! Data written to: config/application/data
```

You can also fetch the properties from the KV by using the following command,

```
$ ./consul kv get config/application/data
cassandra:
  host: 127.0.0.1:9042,127.0.0.2:9042
  user: my_user
  password: my_pass
```

You can also view the properties from the Consul Web UI,

[image]

#### Changes to bootstrap.yml

You need to modify your `bootstrap.yml` slightly. Here are the changes:

- `prefix` value to `config`
- `defaultContext` value to `application`
- Added `format` to `yaml`
- Added `data-key` by the name of `data` to fetch the YAML blob.

  ```
  spring:
    profiles: default
    cloud:
      consul:
        host: localhost
        port: 8500
        config:
          enabled: true
          prefix: config
          defaultContext: application
          data-key: data
          profileSeparator: '::'
          format: yaml
    application:
      name: spring-boot-consul
  ```

#### Changes to ConsulConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class ConsulConfiguration {

    @Value("${cassandra.host}")
    private String cassandraHost;

    @Value("${cassandra.user}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${cassandra.password}")
    private String password;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        // to validate if properties are loaded
        System.out.println("** cassandra.host: " + cassandraHost);
        System.out.println("** cassandra.user: " + userName);
        System.out.println("** cassandra.password: " + password);
    }
}
```

#### Changes to Application class,

```
@EnableRetry
@RefreshScope
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.test.*")
public class SpringBootConsulApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }

}
```